# design pattern where requirement keeps changing

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Looking for design pattern where-in my requirement keeps on changing or in another word i can say the requirement is not very clear. 
I need to develop stand-alone Windows Forms App using C#. UI design of app may be changed as and when required as per requirement. Not sure from which design pattern shall i start.

Thanks,

Comment: your question is extremely 'vague'

Comment: it is in very general term

Comment: @user3114414 : [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: I _think_ you may want to look at [Separation of Concerns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98734/what-is-separation-of-concerns).

Comment: Are you looking for something like MVVM ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_prototyping ? Just do the minimal to reach next checkpoint if you are expecting something will change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unclear requirements are the #1 reason for software project failure and delay! You simply can't build something as long as you don't know what to build. No 'design pattern' will help you here!

Facing uncertainty, you should generally go with agile programming methods and small components which are as loosely coupled as possible.

Comment: so going for small-components approach will be helpful ?

Comment: It will, if you know what is required from each one of those components. As Thomas said - if you don't know what you want you can't build it!

Comment: It could at least alleviate the pain ;-)...

Answer (score 1):

The best pattern for a project in which you know the requirements are going to change is *SIMPLICITY*.

Don't construct big systems to make your life easier *now* because they will make your life hard in the future. Not only will you have a new feature to put in, but you will have to unpick the system that is already there as it may not even support the feature.

I have been burned by this a few times - I was lazy (which is not always bad!) so i designerd a big, fun-to-code system to do the boring job for me. The requirements then changed and everything was now more complicated to debug and test.

There is no substitute for simplicity. For windows forms, consider an established pattern like model-view-presenter but don't burden yourself with it. Patterns are a means, *not an end*

Answer (score 0):

Generally if something keeps changing it normally only effects 1 layer of your application, like the back end, the front end, the database etc.

If you can at least come up with the most constant constraints you can make your framework using dependency injection and loose coupling to allow you to change implementations at various layers quite easily. Its an open ended question so there is no 1 correct answer, however you want something which will let you swap out *COMPONENTS* easily, so design at the component level, not the the code level.

If you want a project management model which copes well with change look at Agile... or just be pragmatic...